# Forward fill or back fill NaN values in Pandas columns based on grouping of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['USA','USA','MEX','IND','UK','UK','UK'],
                   'Region':['Americas','NaN','NaN','Asia','Europe','NaN','NaN'],
                   'Flower':['Rose','Rose','Lily','Orchid','Dandelion','Dandelion','Dandelion'],
                   'Animal':['Bison','NaN','Golden Eagle','Tiger','Lion','Lion','NaN'],
                   'Game':['Baseball','Baseball','soccer','hockey','cricket','cricket','cricket']})
```

I want to group by `Country` and `Flower` and forward fill or backward fill the columns `Region` and `Animal` where there are missing values. However the column `Game` should remain intact

I have tried this but it didn't work:

```py
df['Region'] = df.groupby(['Country','Flower'])['Region'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill())
```

also :

```py
df.groupby(['Country','Flower'])['Animal', 'Region'].isna().bfill()
```

I want to know how to go about with this.

while this works but it removes the Games column:

`df=df.replace({'NaN':np.nan})`
`df.groupby(['Country','Flower'])['Animal', 'Region'].bfill().ffill()`

And if i do a transform there is a mismatch in the length. Also please note that this is sample dataframe where I had added "NaN" as a string in the original frame it is as np.nan.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know `'NaN'` is not `NaN`

```
df=df.replace({'NaN':np.nan})
df.groupby(['Country','Flower'])['Region'].ffill()
Out[109]: 
0    Americas
1    Americas
2         NaN# since here only have single row , that why stay NaN
3        Asia
4      Europe
5      Europe
6      Europe
Name: Region, dtype: object
```

Second if you need to chain two iid function in `pandas` you need `apply`

```
df.update(df.groupby(['Country','Flower'])['Animal', 'Region'].apply(lambda x : x.bfill().ffill()))                               
df
Out[119]: 
         Animal Country     Flower      Game    Region
0         Bison     USA       Rose  Baseball  Americas
1         Bison     USA       Rose  Baseball  Americas
2  Golden Eagle     MEX       Lily    soccer       NaN
3         Tiger     IND     Orchid    hockey      Asia
4          Lion      UK  Dandelion   cricket    Europe
5          Lion      UK  Dandelion   cricket    Europe
6          Lion      UK  Dandelion   cricket    Europe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your dataframe code to actually include `np.nan`s, then the code you provided actually works. Although nans appear as normal text 'Nan', you can't create a dataframe writing that text by hand because that will be interpreted as a string, not an actual missing value.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['USA','USA','MEX','IND','UK','UK','UK'],
                   'Region':['Americas',np.nan,np.nan,'Asia','Europe',np.nan,np.nan],
                   'Flower':['Rose','Rose','Lily','Orchid','Dandelion','Dandelion','Dandelion'],
                   'Animal':['Bison',np.nan,'Golden Eagle','Tiger','Lion','Lion','NaN'],
                   'Game':['Baseball','Baseball','soccer','hockey','cricket','cricket','cricket']})
```

Then, this:

```py
df['Region'] = df.groupby(['Country','Flower'])['Region'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill())
```

actually yields this:

```
         Animal Country     Flower      Game    Region
0         Bison     USA       Rose  Baseball  Americas
1           NaN     USA       Rose  Baseball  Americas
2  Golden Eagle     MEX       Lily    soccer       NaN
3         Tiger     IND     Orchid    hockey      Asia
4          Lion      UK  Dandelion   cricket    Europe
5          Lion      UK  Dandelion   cricket    Europe
6           NaN      UK  Dandelion   cricket    Europe
```

Comment: True, just copied his suggestion as it was to emphasize there was nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

> As Mex and Lily are only rows and moreover their region value is nan, fillna         function not able to find appropriate group value.
> If we catch the exception while fillna group mode then those value where there is no group will be left as it is. Then apply ffill and bfill to cover those value which doesn't have appropriate group

```
df_stack = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['USA','USA','MEX','IND','UK','UK','UK'],'Region': ['Americas',np.nan,np.nan,'Asia','Europe',np.nan,np.nan],'Flower': ['Rose','Rose','Lily','Orchid','Dandelion','Dandelion','Dandelion'],'Animal':['Bison',np.nan,'Golden Eagle','Tiger','Lion','Lion',np.nan],'Game':  ['Baseball','Baseball','soccer','hockey','cricket','cricket','cricket']})
print("-------Before imputation------")
print(df_stack)
def fillna_Region(grp):
    try:
        return grp.fillna(grp.mode()[0])
    except BaseException as e:
        print('Error as no correspindg group: ' + str(e))
df_stack["Region"] = 
df_stack["Region"].fillna(df_stack.groupby(['Country','Flower']) ['Region'].transform(lambda grp : fillna_Region(grp)))
df_stack["Animal"] = 
df_stack["Animal"].fillna(df_stack.groupby(['Country','Flower']) ['Animal'].transform(lambda grp : fillna_Region(grp)))
df_stack = df_stack.ffill(axis = 0)
df_stack = df_stack.bfill(axis =0)
print("-------After imputation------")
print(df_stack)
```